# Mesh jumping to armature origin with automatic weighting

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I have an issue in blender where when I assign automatic weight to the object's mesh. It deforms to the object's origin.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccFkm2NTQRg) is a video showcasing the issue.

I use Rigify to generate the armature and Blender 2.9. The topology of the model is good. I am really at my wit's end with it.

Comment: We need to see what the rig looks like in the rest position.  It looks as if somewhere or another, some bone in it posed strangely.  If this is a straight "generate rig" from the metarig, then something has gone wrong with the bone constraints.

Comment: I Think this is what you wanted correct? I also set the origin of the armature to the 3d mass and it changes the way the automatic weights work. It always seems to point towards the origin point. [Video of rest position](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bpCd35Vf_R8)

Comment: Then there's something weird going on with the constraints in the rig.  I'd have to see a file to be able to tell you more.

Comment: Okay, So here is the blender file [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lTb8Z8N2DItkSWhUf-yzchRePULDPVP4/view?usp=sharing)

Sorry for taking four hours to respond.

Comment: There's something really weird going on there.  I don't know what it is; I suspect that something is way bugged.  I'll continue to look, will let you know if I figure anything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's generate a rig and then look at the deform layer.  I'll disable shapes so that I can see what I'm doing.  I'm using b-bone display instead:

[image]

So the reason I'm using b-bone display here is, because, look at that bone I have selected-- for some reason, your metarig has generated this as a 10-segment bendy bone.  It shouldn't be; that's basically turning all of your deform bones into tentacles, which are deforming even in rest because of their intro/outro angles.

To fix this, simply set all the deform bones b-bone segments to "1":

1. Switch rig to layer 30 (deform bones.)  Select a bone, then select all bones.
2. On properties/bone/bendy bones, set Segments to 1.
3. Right click in the same segments field and select "Copy to Selected".

Now, you can parent it to the armature with automatic weights and it'll be fine.

I have no idea how Rigify thought that it should turn all of your deform bones into bendy bones-- I'm not up on all of the customization that can be done with Rigify armatures-- but that's the fix.

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you so much.